# ERROR #gatsby-source-wordpress_111002 & Error: Request failed with status code 429

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-plugin, http-status-code-429

my gatsby project suddenly stopped working after this error as it was working fine previously

> ERROR #gatsby-source-wordpress_111002
>
> gatsby-source-wordpress  Error: Request failed with status code 429
> at createError (D:\Projects\Project1\oclouds\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
> at settle (D:\Projects\Project1\oclouds\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
> at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\Projects\Project1\oclouds\node_modules\gatsby-source-wordpress\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:269:11)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
> at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
>
> Error occurred while fetching nodes of the "Post" type.`

i have tried all solution found online including decreasing the number in schema.requestConcurrency

here is my plugin code in gatsby-config.js

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
  options: {
    url: process.env.WPGRAPHQL_URL,
  },
  schema: {
    timeout: 1000000,
    perPage: 10,
    requestConcurrency: 5,
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

> i have tried all solution found online including decreasing the
> number in schema.requestConcurrency

Your `schema` object is not properly set. You should do something like:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
  options: {
    url: process.env.WPGRAPHQL_URL,
    schema: {
      timeout: 1000000,
      perPage: 10,
      requestConcurrency: 5,
    },
  },
}
```

`schema` is a property from `options`, as you can see in the [docs](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/plugin-options.md#schemapreviewrequestconcurrency).

I'm not sure if this will fix your issue since there are not many details but this certainly will fix your trial.

Comment: thanks Ferran, well updated the schema object, still no luck

Answer (score 1):

If code is `429` then that means too many requests. Just increase the request limit in your `graphql query`.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that could be causing this issue:

1. Wrong URL. Ensure that the URL is in the following format:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        url: `https://myurl.com/graphql`,
      },
    },
```

2. Self-signed certificate error when developing locally. To fix it, simply add the following code to the top of your `gatsby-node.js` file:

`process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"`

3. Ensure you do have the `WP Gatsby` and `WP Graphql` plugins installed. Deactivate all the other plugins temporarily to make sure they're not causing an issue. In my case, for some reason the `WPGraphQL WooCommerce (WooGraphQL)` plugin was problematic.

Here is more information that may helpful:

[Quick start guide for Gatsby + Wordpress](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/getting-started.md)

[Fixing gatsby-wordpress-source error](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9196#issuecomment-437474219)